# JSpinner#commitEdit Doesn't Throw ParseException

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple spinner application. The spinner is created with a SpinnerNumberModel, and a JSpinner.NumberEditor using the format string "###":

```
spinner_ = new JSpinner( new SpinnerNumberModel( 0, 0, 500, 1 ) );
spinner_.setEditor( new JSpinner.NumberEditor( spinner_, "###" ) );
```

I have a commit procedure that looks like this:

```
try
{
    spinner_.commitEdit();
    System.out.println( "success" ); 
}
catch ( ParseException exc )
{
    System.out.println( exc ); 
}
```

However, no matter what value I type into the editor (for example, "nuts") I do not get a ParseException; the commit will cause the value to revert to the previously committed value, but does not throw an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Sample program follows.

```
public class TestSpinner
    implements Runnable
{
    private final JFrame    frame_;
    private final JSpinner  spinner_;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread( new TestSpinner() ).start();
    }

    public TestSpinner()
    {
        frame_ = new JFrame( "Spinner Test" );
        spinner_ = new JSpinner( new SpinnerNumberModel( 0, 0, 500, 1 ) );
        spinner_.setEditor( new JSpinner.NumberEditor( spinner_, "###" ) );        
    }

    public void run()
    {
        JPanel  panel   = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        frame_.getContentPane().add( panel );

        JButton okButton    = new JButton( "OK" );
        okButton.addActionListener( x -> commit() );

        panel.add( spinner_ );
        panel.add( okButton );
        frame_.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame_.pack();
        frame_.setVisible( true );
    }

    public void commit()
    {
        try
        {
            spinner_.commitEdit();
            System.out.println( "success" ); 
        }
        catch ( ParseException exc )
        {
            System.out.println( exc ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `JSpinner` is been validated BEFORE your `commit` method is been called, therefore, when it's value is invalid, it resorts back to the last known valid value.  Generally speaking, there's no need for you to call commit in this scenario, as the field is "validated" on focus lost

Comment: Oh, and this `new Thread(new TestSpinner()).start();` is stupid, sorry, but it is, you should not be creating your UI outside of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for how you should be starting your GUIs

Comment: Thanks for the help.